# nginx reverse proxy - how to hide client ip

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, clientip

I am working on a project which requires the installation of a reverse proxy before the webserver (game.example.com)

I have done the installation and currently I am working on the headers. I want to hide the client's IP and only the reverse proxy IP to be appearing on the destination server.

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name game.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /root/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/example.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://game.example.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;}
}
```

and a simple html page displays the IP from the other side (sorry for the long code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User and Reverse Proxy IP Display</title>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var userIPElement = document.getElementById("user-ip");
            var userLocationElement = document.getElementById("user-location");
            var reverseProxyIPElement = document.getElementById("reverse-proxy-ip");

            // Function to retrieve user's IP address
            var getUserIP = function() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            // If the request is successful, display the user's IP address
                            var userIP = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).ip;
                            userIPElement.innerText = userIP;

                            // Once user's IP is retrieved, get location and reverse proxy IP
                            getUserLocation(userIP);
                            getReverseProxyIP();
                        } else {
                            // If there's an error, display an error message
                            userIPElement.innerText = "Error retrieving user IP";
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.open("GET", "https://api.ipify.org?format=json");
                xhr.send();
            };

            // Function to retrieve user's location
            var getUserLocation = function(userIP) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            // If the request is successful, display the user's location
                            var locationData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            var userLocation = locationData.city + ", " + locationData.region + ", " + locationData.country_name;
                            userLocationElement.innerText = userLocation;
                        } else {
                            // If there's an error, display an error message
                            userLocationElement.innerText = "Error retrieving user location";
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.open("GET", "https://ipapi.co/" + userIP + "/json/");
                xhr.send();
            };

            // Function to retrieve reverse proxy's IP address
            var getReverseProxyIP = function() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            // If the request is successful, display the reverse proxy's IP address
                            reverseProxyIPElement.innerText = xhr.getResponseHeader("X-Real-IP");
                        } else {
                            // If there's an error, display an error message
                            reverseProxyIPElement.innerText = "Error retrieving reverse proxy IP";
                        }
                    }
                };
                xhr.open("GET", "/");
                xhr.send();
            };

            // Start by getting the user's IP address
            getUserIP();
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>Welcome to Example</h1>
    <h2>User and Reverse Proxy IP Display</h2>
    <p>User's IP address: <span id="user-ip">Loading...</span></p>
    <p>User's location: <span id="user-location">Loading...</span></p>
    <p>Reverse proxy's IP address: <span id="reverse-proxy-ip">Loading...</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I want the reverse proxy's IP to be displayed and not the client IP, but currently I just get the client IP and not the reverse proxy's. Example of the current webpage below:

```
Welcome to Example
User and Reverse Proxy IP Display

User's IP address: 79.xx.xx.xxx

User's location: xxxxx, xxxxxxx, GRxxxxx

Reverse proxy's IP address: {blank}
```

I appreciate any information